# How does one create a new html page with php?

Tags: php, html, sql

I was wondering how one would go about making a new html page if certain conditions were met.

My example/issue:

I have an "archives" that lists the past 30 blog entries I have made on my site, however I would like entries 30-60 to display on "page 2" of the archives. Is there any way to do this automatically so a new page will create itself every 30 entries or do I have to manually create a new page each time?

Comment: With a dynamic server process, one generally doesn't "dynamically create a new HTML page". Rather, given a set of inputs (in this case, the "pagination" information) the PHP returns the HTML dynamically after performing whatever data-select operations are required. It sounds like you may also be interested in *caching*.

Comment: Yes, this is standard pagination and database querying. You use `LIMIT` to specify the number of items you want, and an offset, and render them according to the page number you are supplied in the URL.

Comment: Yes, to add to @user2864740's point, in general you'd have one PHP script to do this, and at no point is a static HTML saved to disk. (There are uses for that, in particular with caching, but I wouldn't worry about that for now).

Answer (score 3):

That isn't how "dynamic" pages work. You (almost) never actually create new HTML documents on the fly; instead, PHP examines the requested URL and serves up the matching results. You would use something like mod_rewrite to redirect all requests to a single PHP script.